# Non empty object is not returned - Node.js

Tags: node.js

My server returns an empty object if it gets to the last condition, where code is 204:

```
exports.get_group_profile = function(req, res) {
 Work.findById(req.params.work_id, function(err, work) {
    if (err || !work)
        return res.send(404);
    if (work.admin.id === req.user._id){
        console.log('here');
        return res.json(200, work.profile);
    }
    if (work.users.indexOf(req.user._id)> -1)
        return res.json(201, work.profile);
    if (work.invited.indexOf(req.user._id) > -1)
        return res.json(202, work.profile);
    for (var i=0;i<work.appliers.length;i++) {
        if (work.appliers[i].id == req.user._id)
            return res.json(203, work.profile);
    }
    if (work.visibility!=0){
        console.log(work.profile);
        return res.json(204, work.profile);
    }
    return res.send(404);
});
```

};

Any condition but this one returns work.profile (which is a virtual in mongoDB) properly. The log before the return prints the object I need but I have no trace of it on my client side. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this website: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

This is why you are not seeing anything on the client side.

Comment: You made me realize responses were more meaningful than just a way to talk to my client side! Do you know what is processing this behavior in Express ? And thank you for the link !

Comment: I'd guess that, since it's written in some RFC, Express should be ignoring the second argument.